# Inserting more than 50k records at a time to Oracle database table

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, apache-poi

I need to insert more than 50k records to oracle database table, The process is i am reading data from External excel file and trying to insert into table at a time which have more than 50k records.The data should be inserted into table efficiently.I am able to retrieve data from excel file, now the data is ready with me, but anybody could suggest me the best way to insert data in to oracle database table.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please share it with us that way we can help you improve what you have.

Comment: the fastest is to use oracle loader. via java you should handle batches of 1000 - 10000 records and use jdbc batch inserts

Comment: Did you tried to load using batches? instead of trying to insert all 50k records at one shot?

Comment: @JonTaylor using apache poi i am able to read entire records from excel file but i couldn't make a decision on how to insert entire data in to oracle database table

Comment: @PradeepSimha i haven't tried to load using batches..

Comment: @opi can you share me a url to do it using oracle loader..

Comment: i don't know why downvotes for my question is there anything wrong in my question..?

Comment: @MuraliPrasanth, try dividing list into chunks of 1000s and then do batch updates, if required put entire things in a transaction so that all parts are inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [JDBC batch updates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/statement.html#1000712)

You could create one `PreparedStatement`, loop through the data you want to insert and add as batches, and execute in the end.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bulk upload tool designed specifically for this [SQL Loader](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aLoader_FAQ)

Comment: how do i do with an excel file

Comment: You should read the provided link. Your question is handled there specifically: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aLoader_FAQ#How_does_one_load_MS-Excel_data_into_Oracle.3F